# Python Image processing screenshots

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program than will detect when my mouse pointer will change icon and automatically send out a mouse click. Is there a better way to do this than to take screenshots and parse the image for the mouse icon?

EDIT:
I'm running my program on windows 7.
I'm trying to learn some image processing and make a simple flash game i made automated. 
Rules: when the curses changes shape, click to get a point.

Also what imaging modules for python will allow you to take a specific size screenshot not just the whole screen? This question has moved to a new thread: "[Taking Screen shots of specific size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697210)"

Comment: Do you only want to do this when your program is active and controlling the mouse? If so, it's not that hard… but it also doesn't seem that useful (wherever you were setting the cursor, just trigger the click event there, instead of setting the cursor and then catching it elsewhere to fake a click). If not, there is no real cross-platform way to do it, so you'll have to tell us what platform you care about.

Comment: Meanwhile, your "Also" is (a) a completely separate question that shouldn't be crammed into this question, and (b) too open-ended as written. If you can narrow it down, it might be a good question to file separately. For example, something like: "In the three imaging modules Foo, Bar, and Baz (with links) that otherwise meet my requirements, how do I take a specific size screenshot instead of the entire screen. If they can't do it, I'd be happy to hear about others that can."

Comment: That being said, every imaging module I know about that take screenshots—PIL `ImageGrab.grab`, `pygame.surface.save`, etc.—all operate on a specific region of the screen; which one are you using that doesn't provide that?

Comment: Thanks abarnet, hope my edits make things clearer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this in Windows is to install either a global message hook with [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [`SetWinEventHook`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373640%28VS.85%29.aspx). (Alternatively, you could build a DLL that embeds Python and hooks into the browser or its Flash wrapper app and do it less intrusively from within the app, but that's much more work.)

The message you want is [`WM_SETCURSOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Note that this is the message sent by Windows to the app to ask whether it wants to change the cursor, not a message sent when the cursor changes. So, IIRC, you will want to put a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` and a `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET` and check `GetCursorInfo` before and after to see if the app has done so.

So, how do you do this from Python? Honestly, if you don't already know both `win32api` and friends from the [`pywin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) package, and how to write Windows message procs in some language, you probably don't want to. If you *do* want to, I'd start off with the (abandoned) [pyHook](http://uncassist.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/uncassist/pyHook/) project from UNC Assist. Even if you can't get it working, it's full of useful source code.

You should also search SO for `[python] SetWinEventHook` and `[python] SetWindowsHookEx`, and google around a bit; there are some examples out there (I even wrote one here somewhere…)

You can look at higher-level wrapper frameworks like [`pywinauto`](http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/index.html) and [`winGuiAuto`](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/winGuiAuto.py.html), but as far as I know, none of them has much help for capturing events.

I believe there are other tools, maybe [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/), that have all the functionality you need, but not in Python module. (AutoIt, for example, has its own VB-like scripting language instead.)