# Taking Screen shots of specific size

Tags: python

What imaging modules for python will allow you to take a specific size screenshot (not whole screen)?
I have tried PIL, but can't seem to make ImageGrab.grab() select a small rectangle
and i have tried PyGame but i can't make it take a screen shot outside of it's main display panel

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [pyscreenshot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyscreenshot) module. 
The `pyscreenshot` module can be used to copy the contents of the screen to a `PIL` image memory or file. 
You can install it using `pip`.

```
$ sudo pip install pyscreenshot
```

Usage:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
# fullscreen
im=ImageGrab.grab()
im.show()

# part of the screen
im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,500,500))
im.show()

# to file
ImageGrab.grab_to_file('im.png')
```

Comment: unfortunately no. http://pyscreenshot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pyscreenshot.grab_to_file

Comment: im.save() suffices

Answer (score 6):

> I have tried PIL, but can't seem to make ImageGrab.grab() select a small rectangle

What did you try?

As the documentation for [`ImageGrab`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageGrab.html) clearly states, the function has a `bbox` parameter, and:

> The pixels inside the bounding box are returned as an “RGB” image. If the bounding box is omitted, the entire screen is copied.

So, you only get the whole screen if you don't pass a `bbox`.

Note that, although I linked to the Pillow docs (and you should be using Pillow), old-school PIL's docs [say the same thing](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagegrab.htm):

> The bounding box argument can be used to copy only a part of the screen.

So, unless you're using a really, really old version of PIL (before 1.1.3, which I believe is more than a decade out of date), it has this feature.

Comment: im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,500,500))

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Additionally it works best on Windows

Answer (score 4):

1) Use pyscreenshot, ImageGrab works but only on Windows

2) Grab the image and box it, then save that image

3) Don't use ImageGrab.grab_to_file, it saves the full size image

4) You don't need to show the image with im.show if you just want to save a screenshot

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,500,500))

im.save('im.png')
```

Comment: Doesn't `ImageGrab.grab()` scale the image? In your example, would the size of the image be 490x490 pixels?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Python MSS](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss).

From documentation to capture only a part of the screen:

```
import mss
import mss.tools


with mss.mss() as sct:
    # The screen part to capture
    monitor = {"top": 160, "left": 160, "width": 160, "height": 135}
    output = "sct-{top}x{left}_{width}x{height}.png".format(**monitor)

    # Grab the data
    sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)

    # Save to the picture file
    mss.tools.to_png(sct_img.rgb, sct_img.size, output=output)
    print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pyscreenshot at linux or windows platforms . I am using Ubuntu it works for me. You can force if subprocess is applied setting it to false together with mss gives the best performance.

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import time
t1 = time.time()
imgScreen = ImageGrab.grab(backend="mss", childprocess=False)
img = imgScreen.resize((640,480))
img.save("screen.png")
t2 = time.time()
print("The passing time",(t2-t1))
```

Comment: How to close the browser that it opens once screenshot is taken