# How to take screenshots in Python with certain pixel range?

Tags: python, screenshot

Does anyone know of any modules or any way in Python to take a screenshot of a certain pixel range on the screen? I have been looking but couldn’t find anything online.

Comment: I'm scared it won't be native to Python. Must be some graphics library or window manager be able to assist?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19697210/939986), [this](http://pyscreenshot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pyscreenshot.grab_to_file), [this](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89032/PIL.ImageGrab.grab), and [this](http://www.effbot.org/imagingbook/imagegrab.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try This one

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

img=ImageGrab.grab()
img=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,500,500))

ImageGrab.grab_to_file('img.jpg')
```

Comment: in current version (2020) it is `img=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,500,500))`
n\ `img.save('img.png')`.
Line 2 in the above answer is not needed.